# Custom People picker that searches for users belonging to a particular OU

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We need to have a custom people picker which can only search for users belonging to a particular OU in AD.  Can we create a custom people picker with customized LDAP queries?

Also for a particular page the people picker should search for users in one OU and for other page in different OU.  Hence the option of setting LDAP queries with powershell is ruled out.  I have to make my own custom people picker but the problem is we do not understand how to set these filters in code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This request dosn't seems really need to be done in sharepoint, by using System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry, you can scan the nodes and users in AD and apply certain filter, more examples can be found in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

I have done in the passed is query the /_vti_bin/search.asmx sharepoint search service.

with a scope set to SPSPeople. I like to user MSSQLFT queries

You should be able to filter on domain names aswell